# Can the subject of the verb “troubler” be a person

Tags: verbes

One of the definitions of the verb troubler is [Éveiller le désir, la sensualité de quelqu'un : Son charme le troublait profondément](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/troubler/80002). [image]

Can the subject of this particular definition of the verb troubler be a person?

Answer (score 1):

Oui, bien sûr. Ce qui peut troubler dans cette acception ne peut d'ailleurs guère être qu'une caractéristique d'une personne ou la personne en son entier.

> *Lucinde, en effet, l’appelait malgré lui, il sortait de la beauté de cette femme quelque chose d’attractif qui faisait venir à elle ; rien de plus doux que son visage, rien de plus simple que son maintien, et pourtant **toute sa personne troublait** ; de suite on se sentait disposé à l’adorer, à mourir pour elle, puis tout à coup le cœur se révoltait et l’on se mettait à la haïr sans cause.*
>
> Gustave Flaubert, *l'Éducation sentimentale*, 1845.

> *Pour la première fois, **un homme me troublait** au plus profond de mon cœur* et de ma chair.
> Jean Cordelier, *Les yeux de la tête*, 1953.

Comment: Personnellement je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'une réponse à la question posée. OP demande si le sujet peut être une personne, un être vivant, pas si le terme « personne » peut être sujet de la phrase.

Comment: @Exocytosis Il semble bien que dans cette phrase "toute sa personne" représente un individu et non le terme "personne".

Comment: « Sa personne », « Son âme », font référence à des attributs du sujet. Ce que OP demande est différent. Il/elle demande si le sujet du verbe troubler peut être UNE personne.

Comment: @Exocytosis Je veux bien que *sa personne* puisse être discutable, encore que je ne partage pas ton opinion, mais *un homme* te pose un problème aussi ?

Answer (score 1):

Oui.
Exemple:
« Elle avait une paire d ' yeux séduisants mais durs et tenaces. Quand je scrutais le fond de ses yeux , je pensais à une louve affamée. **Elle me troublait.** »

Amin Zaoui « Festin de mensonges », 2008.